# Bitcoins did not arrive

Tags: bitcoin-core

A few days ago I transferred bitcoins from www.blockchain.info to the Bitcoin Core - Wallet, but the bitcoin did never arrive, I made a Request and the address was: 15Yw9RpFY28cN1fjwQPQfqvxjGg9TXRLmB then I send the bitcoin to that address from blockchain but they never arrived.
My Bitcoin Core - Wallet is still synchronising with the network, it is 3 years and 21 weeks behind, is this the problem they didn't arrive?

Thanks,

Comment: The stated [address has received one transaction](https://blockchain.info/address/15Yw9RpFY28cN1fjwQPQfqvxjGg9TXRLmB).

Answer (score 0):

dont worry

your 0.30811325 btc sent by [this transaction](https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/tx/96179903f29cbc59f56e1cdf9a72fa8d2502301b44583a15e9641d7833fd685a) are waiting for you

you have to synchronize your client to see and use your funds

Comment: Thank you! That's a relieve,
What is the average time of the synchronising?

Comment: Depending on your hardware, somewhere between hours and weeks.